# htaccess load resources from directory

Tags: web-services, apache, .htaccess

I want to make a htaccess RewriteRule with a RewriteCond

What I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sql.site.ro)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ro-site-sql/index.php?x=$1
```

I want all requests sent to sql.site.ro to be served from the `/ro-site-sql` directory.
So if the URI is `sql.site.ro/index.php` the server will go to `/ro-site-sql/index.php`, or if URI is `sql.site.ro/images/small/9954.png` the server will go to `/ro-site-sql/images/small/9954.png`.

The problem is that if I make

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sql.site.ro)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ro-site-sql/$1
```

I get an Internal Server Error, and if I make

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sql.site.ro)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ro-site-sql/index.php?x=$1
```

I get `Array ( [x] => ro-site-sql/index.php )` inside of `/ro-site-sql/index.php`. Should it not be just `index.php`, without the `ro-site-sql/` part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sql.site.ro$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 ^(\w+/)+\w+\.\w+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ro-site-sql/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sql.site.ro$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(\w+/)+\w+\.\w+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ro-site-sql/index.php?x=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This should work to identify actual files and access those and pass anything else to index.php.

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite engine loops over .htaccess files until no more substitutions occur.   You need to ensure that this loop stops after the first replacement.  There are various ways to do this.  Perhaps the easiest to understand is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sql.site.ro)$
RewriteCond $1           !index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       ro-site-sql/index.php?x=$1    [L,QSA]
```

Add the [L] flag because this is the last rule on this cycle and [QSA] if you also have other parameters sometimes.